# How to make layout like google play home?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, google-play, android-gridview

How to make layout like this? Its looks like listview with many gridviews or listview of many different layouts. I have no idea how should i make this. On scrolling its get totally changed and also it have different more button colors. Please help me if anyone have solution.
[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

This question is so straight forward! Don't post such kind of questions before you dig and analyze.

If I'm designing this then this how I do. (This is just a sample of static design). But `Google` did lot's of work here and its a dynamic content.

First the parent layout will be `android.support.design.widget.CoordinateLayout` and there is `ScrollView` or `NestedScrollView` as child.

Then comes `SearchBar`. There is a separate [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html) for that. Kindly go through.

Third `TableLayout` with 2 columns and 3 rows which holds `Buttons`

Fourth is custom `ViewHolder` with title, subtitle and button and custom `CardView` at bottom of the title contains `ImageView` and `ToolBar` below with `Menu`.

And all these cards will have its own components etc.,